# Firebase Functions deploy error : Error occurred while parsing your function triggers

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendPushNotification = functions.database.ref('/Rollerbanken/{id}').onWrite((event => {
    const payload = {
    notification: {
    title: 'New message arrived',
    body: 'come check it',
    badge: '1',
    sound: 'default',
    }
};
    return admin.database().ref('fcmToken').once('value').then(allToken => {
    if(allToken.var ()) {
    const token = Object.keys(allToken.val());
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload).then(responds => {
            });
        };
    });
});
```

> Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.
>
> /private/var/folders/s3/gnf3bs6s0_n5jx27n2zj3xwr0000gn/T/fbfn_75373XQetWUjR4EdN/index.js:21
>   });  ^
>
> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
>       at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
>       at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:588:28)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:18:11

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you ref is not valid.  The database reference is case sensitive and should be like this

```
functions.database.ref('/Rollerbanken/{id}').onWrite(
```

You have the reference to database with D in uppercase. It should be lower case.

Go through this for complete implementatio

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events
Hope that helps.

Comment: D in uppercase? Whats that? Sorry i am now to firebase.

Comment: You wrote Database it should be database.

Comment: Your implementation is not complete.

Comment: That deals with an another issue. Post a seperate question for that. And accept the answer above and upvote it so it can be helful to others too. Thanks